# Will wearable service ever be killed?

Tags: android, wear-os

The Android Wearable service is essentially an Android Service component (correct me if this wrong). And we have it in the manifest file like below.

```
    <service android:name=".WearableService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

As far as I know there are loads of apps there which kills services to release memory, do we need to do anything for the wearable service to respawn once it's killed or it is a system service that can never be killed?

Comment: it may be killed, and restart by system automatically.

Comment: @JiangYD is right. It may be killed but will be restarted on demand. You don't have to care about its lifecycle as it's managed by the system. But you also cannot assume it will be running forever.